# Calling first HTML page inside modal dialog of second HTML page in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have this folder structure of controllers, routers, services and views

```
study/controller.js
      router.js
      service.js

files/controller.js
      router.js
      service.js

view/files.html
     study.html
```

study and files HTML views use the corresponding JS files defined in their folders. I have a unique case where inside the study view page, I launch a modal dialog that has to show the files view HTML page. On the files view page, user selects a text, and that text then needs to be displayed inside the text on the modal dialog of study view.

The files controller is shown below

```
myapp.controller('FileController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$filter', 'resolvedFile', 'FileService',
function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $location, $filter, resolvedFile, FileService) {
    if (angular.isArray(resolvedFile)) {
        resolvedFile.$promise.then(function(files) {
            $scope.files = files;
        });
    }
```

}]);

The files router is defined as shown below

```
myApp
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider','$translateProvider', 'USER_ROLES',
    function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider, USER_ROLES) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/files', { // listing files
                templateUrl: 'views/files.html',
                controller: 'FileController',
                resolve:{
                    resolvedFile: ['$route', 'FileService', function ($route, FileService) {
                        return FileService.files.query();
                    }]
                },
                access: {
                    authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                }
            })
    }]);
```

In the study view I pop up a modal dialog using ng-class="modal fade" and then modal has a header and a body. My biggest problem right now is how to show the files view in this modal dialog. This is how I have attempted so far. Here is the study controller code

```
$scope.openFileChoser = function(){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/files.html',
            controller: 'FileController',
            resolve: {
                resolvedFile : function () {
                    return FileService.files.query();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is once you get to the study controller modal code, how do you make the files.html call the FileService.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is because you have the same controller `FileController` with different resolve parameters in your `$routeProvider` configuration, in one case it's `resolvedFile` and in another - `files`. Angular expects resolves to be consistent. So, either use different controllers, or add both `resolve`s in each path.

Comment: I changed the syntax and that would not give the same error but how do I make the modal page that is files.html that comes up in the dialog to make the service call.

Comment: I don't understand the question. I suggest you post a separate question with more details.